# Firestore & Python, updating a specific object within an array

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

Below is an example of the data that I have within my Firestore Application.

[image]

I am looking to update the "prices" object using python, is this a possibility? I am finding it increasingly hard to get all the way to the data.

I don't want you to code this for me, i'm merly asking if it is possible and just some quick guidance on how to achieve it.

My api will fetch prices, then find the "ID" of the specific conditions which is stored in the "id" field within the condtion array, if will then update the "prices" object of that found id.

Like I said, is this possible? And a few pointers on how to achieve this would be great!

Kind Regards,
Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating just one field of an array item is not possible.

The most you could do would be to update only an entire array item. You can do this with `arrayRemove()` and `arrayUnion()`. More info [in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array)